# Can functions switch between data types?

Tags: functions, definition

I don't know what the right terminology is so I am using some programming jargon, sorry.

But for example can we say that a function accepts reals and returns naturals? Or accepts complex and returns reals? More generally accepting one type and returning another?

For example $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ defined as having domain natural numbers and codomain natural numbers. Then I can feed it $\sqrt{16} = 4$ with no issue but then $\sqrt{5}$ is not a natural number.

Am I not allowed to mix and match input/return types? What are these properties even called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can take any "input type" and give any "output type".  The "input type" is called the *domain* of the function, and the "output type" is called the *codomain*.  The domain and codomain are allowed to be any sets at all, and do not have to be the same set.

To be more precise, given any two sets $A$ and $B$, a function $f:A\to B$ is a rule which, given any element $a\in A$, produces an output $f(a)$ which is an element of $B$.  Here $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain.  (To be even more precise, such a "rule" is really a subset $S$ of $A\times B$, where for each $a\in A$ there is a unique $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in S$, in which case $b$ is what we call $f(a)$.)

As for your example, there is no function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ with domain and codomain the natural numbers.  For each element of the domain, the function is required to give an output which is in the codomain.  Since $\sqrt{5}$ is not a natural number, the rule $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ does not define a function with domain the natural numbers and codomain the natural numbers.

Comment: So the "image" would be the values that f(a) (over all a in the domain) actually maps to in B? Would image = range? Would preimage be the same as domain?

Comment: What about something like the floor function? Is it valid to say $\lfloor . \rfloor : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as well as $\lfloor . \rfloor : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ or $\lfloor . \rfloor : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ for example? Maybe even $\lfloor . \rfloor : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, as $\mathbb N\subset \mathbb R$ anything that maps $f:A\to \mathbb N$ will also map $f:A \to \mathbb R$.  However the function is not "onto" that domain.

Comment: @fleablood What do you mean "the function is not onto that domain"?

Comment: Yes, the image is all values that $f$ actually takes.  It is sometimes also called "range", though I don't recommend using that term since "range" is also sometimes used as a synonym for "codomain".  The term "preimage" does not have any common meaning on its own.  Instead, we speak of the preimage _of a subset of the codomain_: if $f:A\to B$ and $C\subseteq B$, then the preimage of $C$ is the set $f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in C\}$.

Comment: So when most people ask what the domain and range of a function are they're really meaning to ask what the domain and image are? (I'm asking which terms I should be using for this stuff because I wish to be as unambiguous as I can be)

Comment: As your example of the floor function shows, the same "formula" can describe several different functions (with different domains and codomains).  The function itself consists of not just the formula but also the domain and codomain.  So for instance, the floor function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and the floor function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ are _different_ functions.  (Including the codomain as part of the data of the function is not universal, though, and in particular it is common to omit it in set theory.)

Comment: Uh, I don't know what "most people" mean when they ask what the domain and range of a function are.  In what context?

Comment: Asking for the "domain and range of a function" is a common thing to do when learning the basics of functions

Comment: Such questions typically have little to do with the actual mathematical definition of functions.  They are instead asking about some particular algebraic expression and are asking for what inputs the expression can be evaluated and what possible outputs there are.  (So, this is the domain and image of a certain function, but they haven't actually precisely defined what the function is since they just wrote a formula without telling you the domain and codomain.)

Comment: Is there a formal way to describe a function?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "formal".

Comment: For example how would I say "the function $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + 5$ where the inputs are reals and the outputs are integers"? $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor + 5, f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$? Or is there some other notation that encapsulates these?

Comment: Either that expression in words or those symbols would be a perfectly fine way to say that (though normally one would say "domain" instead of "inputs" and "codomain" instead of "outputs").

Answer (score 2):

Functions have a **domain** and a **range**.  The domain is the input(s) into the function and the range is the output of the function.  The domain could be natural numbers and the range could be real numbers, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes, a function can map from any set $A$ to any set $B$ ($f:A\to B$).  The sets don't have to have *any* intrinsic relations to each other.  So we can easily have $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb N$ or from $g:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ or $h:\{$mathetical symbols$\} \to \{$elephants whose middle name is Fred$\}$.  (Ex:  $h(+) = $Tantor Fred Bigguy of the Santa Fe Zoo; $f(\sum)= $Babar Fred Gibbs of the Indonesian Art Institute....)$

No.

To be a function $f:A\to B$ we must have that for all $a \in A$ then $f(a)$ is a well-defined unambiguous element of $B$.

In your example $f: \mathbb N to \mathbb N$ via $f(n) =\sqrt{n}$ is not a function because if $n \in \mathbb N$ but $n$ is not a perfect square then $f(n)$ is *not* well-defined and unambiguous.

However $f: \{1,4,9,.....|k^2 \in \mathbb N\} \to \mathbb N$ via $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is a well defined function.

As is $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ via $f(x) =\sqrt x$.

Comment: Yes.  But those are not "onto" functions.

Comment: It's the way *I* do it.  $f:A\to B$ is a proper way to state the domain and codomain of the function but not how to define what it is.  $f(x) = whatever...$ is a *common* but not the formal way to *describe* what a function is.  I have taken it upon myself to describe functions as $f:A \to B$ via $f(x)= whatever..$ as a means of definitions.  But no, it's not formal.  It's just what I do.

Answer (score 1):

Presented abstractly, a function $f:X\to Y$, for two non-empty sets $X,Y$ is a subset $F$ of $ X\times Y$ such that for each $x\in X$ there exists a unique $z\in F$ such that $z=(x,y)$, some $y\in Y$. In words, a function is any assignment of **precisely one** $y\in Y$ to **every** $x\in X$. Note that this is a reasonable definition of an abstract input/output model.

Let us check  your example. You define $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ by $F=\{(n, \sqrt{n}): n\in\mathbb N\}$. But $F\not\subset \mathbb N\times \mathbb N$, so to make it a function you need to either enlarge the outputs and/or remove some inputs. For a data-type example, if your function is 
$$f:\text{Integers} \to \text{Strings},\quad\text{ defined by }F=\{(n,\text{'n'}): n\in \text{Integers}\}\subset \text{Integers}\times \text{Strings}$$
then the $F$ is a well defined function. Conversely, if you define
$$\tilde f:\text{Integers} \to \text{Strings},\quad\text{ defined by }\tilde F=\{(\text{'n'},\text{n}): \text{'n'}\in \text{Strings}\}\not\subset \text{Integers}\times \text{Strings}$$
as 
$$\text{Strings}\ni\text{'helloworld!'}\mapsto \text{helloworld!}\not\in \text{Integers},$$
 hence $\tilde F$ is not a function. Possible answer: given two sets $X,Y$, as long as you respect the definition of a function, anything goes (let me know if the notation I use is confusing).